# Is it wrong to use nouns when listing hobbies (as opposed to using verbs)?

Tags: grammar, lists

For example. Would it be wrong to say:

> My hobbies are singing, shopping, **soccer**, and **stationery**.

Why or why not?

Comment: stationery isn't clear to me, do you mean collecting stationery?

Comment: @Zebrafish Anything. Collection, buying, checking, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you mean *stationery;* otherwise you're also including an adjective. As far as your actual question, *singing* and *shopping* are also functioning as nouns. They're [gerunds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund), formed from verbs, but they act as nouns. (There's always some [questioning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205390/what-is-a-gerund-a-noun-or-a-verb-his-smoking-upset-me) as to whether you can say that a gerund *is* a noun. But certainly we *use them* like nouns, as you've done here.)

As a matter of style, I would try to have all the elements in a list be parallel. Especially if you start it with two gerunds, you're setting up an expectation, so it would work best to continue with gerunds (*playing* soccer, and whatever you do with stationery—*making, collecting*?). Otherwise, I would at least mix up the order. Maybe:

> My hobbies are soccer, singing, stationery, and shopping.

But those are just style suggestions. The way you have it is not ungrammatical, and frankly, the style wouldn't even really stand out to me that much. I'd probably note it in passing, but it's not a significant issue.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, my hobbies could be tennis, soccer, football, puzzles, music, piano.

You could say it should be playing tennis, solving puzzles, listening to music, but the above is just fine.